# youtube buffering next video while playing current one

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

I have **videoIds[youtubeIDs]** lined to play youtube videos in mysite which is working fine with the below code.

But when second video starts it lags 1-2 sec to load and the loading youtube icon shows up.

Is there any way to buffer the next video while playing the current video, which will reduce the loading time which results the next video starts instantaneously.

```
<div id="player"></div>
&lt;script>
var youtubeIDs=["qdW21vNQB1E","EcVeqY2QuSI","UOV49oGr2pc"];
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
      /*loadPlaylist:{
        listType:'playlist',
        list:youtubeIDs,
        index:parseInt(0),
        suggestedQuality:'small'
     }, */
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //event.target.loadPlaylist(youtubeIDs,parseInt(2),15,'large');
    event.target.cuePlaylist(youtubeIDs,parseInt(0),15,'large');
    //event.target.playVideo();
    event.target.playVideoAt(0);
  }
```

Comment: Can anyone reply to my question..... spent almost the whole day finding nothing ..no luck

Comment: found a solution? facing the same question